# How to override return value with IMessageSink.SyncProcessMessage

Tags: c#, aop, .net-remoting

I'm trying to roll my own AOP here using an IMessageSink and I have everything working for my purposes but I can't quite figure out how to let my method boundary handler substitute it's own cached value for the original method call.

```
    IMessage IMessageSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)
    {      
        IMessage returnMethod = null;
        object overrideReturnValue = null;
        if(OnEvent(msg, returnMethod, out overrideReturnValue))
        {
            // how do i override the return message
            // and return here?
        }
        returnMethod = next.SyncProcessMessage(msg);
        OnEvent(msg, returnMethod, out overrideReturnValue);
        return returnMethod;
    }
```

Here is the full source of [AOP.cs](https://raw.github.com/gist/2244765/e64a6fd78d28ffda0cd9c61867ee713c107a64fc/AOP.cs) if that might help someone give me a hand here.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer to my question.  Updated [source](https://raw.github.com/gist/2244765/138d51c2644fd98cd34f3182dd7cdd8cdc6b0e8a/AOP.cs) as well.

```
            IMethodCallMessage methodMessage = (IMethodCallMessage)msg;
            returnMethod = new ReturnMessage(overrideReturnValue, methodMessage.Args, methodMessage.ArgCount, methodMessage.LogicalCallContext, methodMessage);
            return returnMethod;
```